# Searching using MySQL: How to escape wildcards

Tags: mysql, search, jdbc, escaping, wildcard

I am currently searching my database with a query (using JDBC) like this:

```
"... AND LCASE(Items.Name) LIKE '%" + searchString.toLowerCase() + "%';"
```

Now, this is obviously very bad, because it allows for SQL injection as well as insertion of wildcard symbols such as % and _.

My question is, how can I do a query such that even if the searchString contains any of these characters, they will be treated literally?

Comment: You would need to escape(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) them probably using EscapeProcessor or your own custom class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, don't use `LCASE` with `LIKE` unless you're using a case-sensitive locale (which is not the default with MySQL).

As far as escaping those characters, just prefix them with a `\` character, so `foo%bar` becomes `foo\%bar`.

(It's been a while since I've used Java, but might this work:)

```
searchString.replaceAll('%', '\\\\%').replaceAll('_', '\\\\_')
```

(or using a regex):

```
Regex r = new Regex('(?:%|_)', '\\\\$&');
r.replaceAll(searchString)
```

As far as preventing SQL injection, just bind the variable as normal:

```
WHERE LCASE(Items.Name) LIKE ?
```

And create the bound string like:

```
'%' + searchString.replaceAll('%', '\\\\%').replaceAll('_', '\\\\_') + '%'
```

Comment: Excellent answer good sir, I just checked the documentation, which I should have done before posting this and was on track to arriving at this solution eventually. Thanks again!

Comment: Just a small edit to make it work: searchString.replaceAll("%", "\\\\%").replaceAll("_", "\\\\_"); It needs so many backspaces because it goes through a regex parser also.

Comment: How do you ensure charset safe escape?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), you can escape them using a slash (`\`) or by specifying your own escape character:

```
"... AND LCASE(Items.Name) LIKE '%" + searchString.toLowerCase() + "%' ESCAPE '/';"
```

You'll have to do a search and replace on the mysql `LIKE` wildcard symbols in your language (Java?), `%` and `_` to replace them with `\%` and `\_` respectively. The other pattern matches you mention above are not (according to the linked docs) supported.

Comment: Thanks, it's all working fine now. And I just checked the documentation and I have removed the other pattern matches.