# Mysql, dealing with String Regex

Tags: mysql, regex, security, code-injection

I'm developing a Java desktop application that connects with a database, and I would like to know the next. It results that as far as I know, Prepared Statements avoid SQL injections while you don't make a direct concatenation with user data, but today I figured out that it doesn't escape String regex (like '%' from the LIKE operator,) due that it just escapes characters that could break up the String itself and alter the query. So, if user does:

```
Search = "%Dogs"; // User input
Query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field LIKE ?";
blah.setString(1, Search);
```

It will return all the rows that contains 'Dogs' at the beginning by injection.

Now I ask:

1-) Is this something bad / dangerous viewing from a global point?

2-) Is there a full list of Regex that Mysql could use from inside a String? if so, can you please share it with me?

Thank you.

Comment: That's not regex, that's LIKE.maybe you meant RLIKE

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching using MySQL: How to escape wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588424/searching-using-mysql-how-to-escape-wildcards)

Comment: @Bohemian the documentation for `LIKE` does say "Pattern matching using SQL simple regular expression comparison."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user uses such meta characters in their search, the results may or may not be catastrophic, but a search for `%%` could be bad.  A valid search for `%Dogs` may also not return the results the user was expecting which affects their experience.

[`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) only offers two meta characters, so you can escape them both on your own when acquired from users (simply using something akin to `Search = Search.replaceAll("%", "\\\\%")`).

Comment: Agreed, another thing, apart LIKE, is there any other Operator / Function / etc that evaluates expressions like that?

Comment: @Neo not like that, but there is `RLIKE`